# Wordpress Standard Fix Errors

Tags: plugins, php

I get the following error while fixing my wordpress plugin standards.

```
 Use placeholders and $wpdb->prepare(); found $sql
```

Below is my code...

```
public function get_db_value() {
    //getting meta_value from wp_usermeta
    global $wpdb;
    $billing_phone = isset($_POST['billing_phone']);
    $sql           = "
    SELECT  user_id,meta_key, meta_value
    FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} 
    WHERE ({$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'billing_phone'";
    $ansatte       = $wpdb->prepare($wpdb->get_results( $sql ));
    $users         = array();
    foreach ( $ansatte as $a ) {
        $users[ $a->user_id ][ $a->meta_key ] = $a->meta_value;
    }
    foreach ( $users as $u ) {
        $nums[] = $u['billing_phone']; //Saving phone numbers in $nums variable

    }
    return $nums;
}
```

Comment: See the docs for the correct syntax of using [`wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) and [`wpdb::get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/), but why don't you just use [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) to get the users?

Comment: @SallyCJ could you please help me using get_users(), i need to get the meta_value based on the value entered by the user.

Comment: @Shehryar, try to read the documentation and adapt your code first, then people can give some help, the code will be much simpler when you use WP functions, instead of trying to write SQL